Adding GUI elements/gizmo's to visualize data
I am working on a script where I add data to an object itself. This data can be extended by adding dividers which are objects saved in a list in this data. I want to visualise this data on the object while it is selected.
I have tried to accomplish this with a custom gizmo (after many other attempts). It works with just one gizmo, except that it remains when I deselect the object. But when I add a for loop to cycle through the dividers it refuses to draw any.

I dont know if Gizmos are the right approach so anty other advice would be greatly appreciated.
How can I get this working? Here is some of the relevant code I have so far:

Class
class Vector3(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    x: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="X", default=0.0)
    y: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Y", default=0.0)
    z: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Z", default=0.0)


class AxisProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    x: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="X")
    y: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Y")
    z: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Z")


class DividerInfo(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    anchor_region: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Divider anchorRegion",
        default=False,
        update=ScalingModule.update_anchor_region,
    )
    fixed_size: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Divider fixedSize", default=False)
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Divider Name", default="")
    position: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Divider Position",
        default=0.0,
    )
    region_percentage: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Divider regionPercentage", default=0.0
    )
    region_size: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Divider regionSize", default=0.0)
    bottom_percentage: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Divider bottomPercentage", default=0.0
    )
    fixed_size_dif: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Divider fixedSizeDif", default=0.0)
    divider_type: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Divider Type")


class RegionInfo(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    position: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Vector3)
    size: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Vector3)
    lock_x_axis: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Region LockXAxis", default=False)
    lock_y_axis: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Region LockYAxis", default=False)
    lock_z_axis: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Region LockZAxis", default=False)
    lock_axis: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=AxisProperties)
    freeze_vertices: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Region freezeVertices", default=False)


class BoundsInfo(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    m_center: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Vector3)
    m_extent: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Vector3)


class ScalingData(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    volume_auto: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Volume Auto",
        description="Automatic or Manual volume setting",
        items=[
            ("AUTO", "Automatic", "Set volume automatically"),
            ("MANUAL", "Manual", "Set volume manually"),
        ],
        default="MANUAL",
        update=ScalingModule.update_volume,
    )
    axis_up: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="3D space axis up",
        description="The axis that points up in 3D space",
        items=[
            ("Z-r", "Z Axis - Right Handed", "Z Axis (Blender, 3DS, Sketchup)"),
            ("Y-r", "Y Axis - Right Handed", "Y Axis (Maya, Godot, Houdini)"),
            ("Z-l", "Z Axis - Left Handed", "Z Axis (Unreal)"),
            ("Y-l", "Y Axis - Left Handed", "Y Axis (Unity, ZBrush, Cinema4D)"),
        ],
        default="Z-r",
    )
    volume: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Vector3)
    size: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Vector3)
    map_rotation: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Vector3)
    map_offset: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Vector3)
    map_scale: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Map Scale", default=1.0)
    divider_ratio: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Divider regionRatio", default=False)
    x_divider_info: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=DividerInfo)
    y_divider_info: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=DividerInfo)
    z_divider_info: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=DividerInfo)
    region_definitions: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=RegionInfo)
    x_anchor: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="X Anchor", default=0)
    y_anchor: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Y Anchor", default=0)
    bounds: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=BoundsInfo)
    child_count: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Child Count", default=0)

GizmoGroup
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy.types import GizmoGroup, Gizmo
from mathutils import Euler, Vector, Matrix

# Define custom shape vertices
custom_shape_verts = (
    (10, -10, 0.0),
    (-10, -10, 0.0),
    (-10, 10, 0.0),
    (10, -10, 0.0),
    (10, 10, 0.0),
    (-10, 10, 0.0),
)

# Define outline shape vertices
outline_shape_verts = (
    (10, -10, 0.0),
    (-10, -10, 0.0),
    (-10, 10, 0.0),
    (10, 10, 0.0),
    (10, -10, 0.0),
    (10, 10, 0.0),
    (-10, -10, 0.0),
    (-10, 10, 0.0),
)


class ScalingWidget(Gizmo):
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_GT_custom_shape_widget"
    bl_target_properties = ({"id": "offset", "type": "FLOAT", "array_length": 1},)

    __slots__ = (
        "custom_shape",
        "outline_shape",
        "init_mouse_y",
        "init_value",
        "outline_thickness",
        "outline_color",
        "shape_color",
        "outline_color_highlight",
        "shape_color_highlight",
        "outline_alpha",
        "outline_alpha_highlight",
        "shape_alpha",
        "shape_alpha_highlight",
    )

    def _update_offset_matrix(self):
        # offset behind the light
        self.matrix_offset.col[3][2] = self.target_get_value("offset")

    def draw(self, context):
        self._update_offset_matrix()
        self.color = self.shape_color
        self.alpha = self.shape_alpha
        self.alpha_highlight = self.shape_alpha_highlight
        self.color_highlight = self.shape_color_highlight
        self.draw_custom_shape(self.custom_shape)
        self.line_width = self.outline_thickness
        self.color = self.outline_color
        self.alpha = self.outline_alpha
        self.color_highlight = self.outline_color_highlight
        self.alpha_highlight = self.outline_alpha_highlight
        self.draw_custom_shape(self.outline_shape)

    def draw_select(self, context, select_id):
        self._update_offset_matrix()
        self.draw_custom_shape(self.custom_shape, select_id=select_id)
        self.line_width = self.outline_thickness
        self.draw_custom_shape(self.outline_shape, select_id=select_id)

    def setup(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "custom_shape"):
            self.custom_shape = self.new_custom_shape("TRIS", custom_shape_verts)
        if not hasattr(self, "outline_shape"):
            self.outline_shape = self.new_custom_shape("LINES", outline_shape_verts)

        # Set the color and alpha properties
        self.shape_color = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0  # Green color for the shape
        self.shape_alpha = 0.2  # Transparency for the shape
        self.shape_color_highlight = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0  # Highlight color for the shape
        self.shape_alpha_highlight = 0.5  # Highlight transparency for the shape

        # Set the outline color and alpha properties
        self.outline_color = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0  # Red outline
        self.outline_alpha = 0.2  # Outline transparency
        self.outline_color_highlight = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0  # Highlight color for the outline
        self.outline_alpha_highlight = 0.5  # Highlight transparency for the outline

        self.outline_thickness = 3.0  # Default thickness for the outline

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.init_mouse_y = event.mouse_y
        self.init_value = self.target_get_value("offset")
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

    def exit(self, context, cancel):
        context.area.header_text_set(None)
        if cancel:
            self.target_set_value("offset", self.init_value)

    def modal(self, context, event, tweak):
        delta = (event.mouse_y - self.init_mouse_y) / 10.0
        if "SNAP" in tweak:
            delta = round(delta)
        if "PRECISE" in tweak:
            delta /= 10.0
        value = self.init_value - delta
        self.target_set_value("offset", value)
        context.area.header_text_set("Divider Position: %.4f" % value)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}


class DividerGizmoGroup(GizmoGroup):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_GT_divider_gizmo"
    bl_label = "Divider Gizmo"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_options = {"3D", "SELECT"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None and hasattr(
            context.object, "scaling_module_data"
        )

    def setup(self, context):
        print("Setting up DividerGizmoGroup")
        obj = context.object
        item = obj.scaling_module_data[0]
        self.x_gizmos = []

        rotation_matrix = Matrix.Rotation(1.5708, 4, "Y")  # 90 degrees in radians
        divider_info = item.x_divider_info[0]
        gizmo = self.gizmos.new(ScalingWidget.bl_idname)
        gizmo.target_set_prop("offset", divider_info, "position")
        gizmo.matrix_basis = obj.matrix_world @ rotation_matrix
        gizmo.scale_basis = 0.25
        gizmo.use_draw_modal = True
        gizmo.use_tooltip = True
        self.x_gizmo = gizmo

    def update_gizmos(self, context):
        print("Updating gizmos")
        obj = context.object
        gizmo = self.x_gizmo
        gizmo.matrix_basis = obj.matrix_world.normalized()
```


Maybe explore updating the view: bpy.context.view_layer.update(). Not sure if before or after trying to set the gizmos

Unfortunately that didnt work. I am starting to think Gizmo's are not the way to go.

What is the format of the data to show? Is it per vertice, per face, per object? Single values of multiple values? It's possible to show some data with geometry nodes and some interface config, but might depend on the data.

My objects have properties that I can manipulate through a panel. One of them is 'position' which describes the position of a divider plane on an axis. I want to visualise this with a non-mesh object, so when I import the object and render it, it doesnt show up. Objects can have multiple dividers/slices.

Oh, you can simply use "empty" objects, arrows, circles, axes.... Or you can use meshes and simply set them to be invisible in render

Yeah, I didnt want to use meshes or empties, but I guess an empty is the way to go for now
